# Oracle can not find a record with a specific field

Tags: index, oracle-11g-r2, corruption

In our application we face an weird situation, consider a table name `TAX` exists in the database, when I query it with `select * from tax where fk_pay = 123456` a record is returned with `id = 654321` but when I query the table with `select * from tax where id = 654321` no record will be returned.
And `id` is the primary key of the table (with available constraint and index).

And I am sure that record exists.

It seems to be a corrupted index, but if that's the case, why it happens, and how can I identify corrupted index?

Comment: and why a vote-down for the question?

Comment: To see if it is the index to blame (highly unlikely), just drop the index and try the queries again.  So, if you `select id from tax order by id` you do see a row with `654321`?  And your query for `fk_pay = 123456` returns a row with a value of `654321` for the column `id`?  What are the data types for `fk_pay` and `id`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select STATUS, LAST_ANALYZED from user_indexes where table_name = 'TAX'` to get the status of the index. The `STATUS` column  has a value of either VALID or UNUSABLE.

But the case you have mentioned doesn't seem to do anything with the index. Please check the data type of the id as Mark Stewart points out. I suspect that whitespace in the data is causing this problem.

Comment: Well I believe it was because the Index... I dropped the index and recreated it and everything started working...